# *iterator causes segfault

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, std

I'm trying to walk through a list. Here are some declarations:

```
list<CG1_Edge*> ActiveEdges;
list<CG1_Edge*>::iterator ActiveEdgeIterator;
```

Sometimes, this code segfaults on line 2:

```
for (this->ActiveEdgeIterator = this->ActiveEdges.begin(); this->ActiveEdgeIterator != this->ActiveEdges.end(); ++this->ActiveEdgeIterator) {
    CG1_Edge* currentEdge = *this->ActiveEdgeIterator;
    if (currentEdge->y_up < y)
        this->ActiveEdges.erase(this->ActiveEdgeIterator);
}
```

Are there any common reasons why this might result in a segfault?

Comment: Just a note of style: I would replace the `for` loop with `std::remove_if` and container resize. Algorithms from the STL hide many iterator-details and make code more readable (when I see a `for` loop I only know that this is some kind of iteration and when I see an STL algorithm I know exactly what it is).

Comment: Begemoth's comment should be the accepted answer. According to the standard erase invalidates "all iterator and references to elements after position". So you'd at _least_ NEED to use rbegin() and rend(). But why not use the std::alogirthms!

Comment: @sehe: no, that is incorrect. `list::erase` does not invalidate the iterators, except those positioned at the erased element.

Comment: My bad, I was referring to the docs of std::vector mistakenly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
for (this->ActiveEdgeIterator = this->ActiveEdges.begin(); this->ActiveEdgeIterator != this->ActiveEdges.end(); ) {
    CG1_Edge* currentEdge = *this->ActiveEdgeIterator;
    if (currentEdge->y_up < y)
        this->ActiveEdgeIterator = this->ActiveEdges.erase(this->ActiveEdgeIterator);
    else
        ++this->ActiveEdgeIterator;
}
```

since erase returns an iterator positionned at the next element.

(Note: having that iterator as a member looks strange.)

Comment: Yeah, this snippet, unlike Alexander's doesn't make you skip one element each time you erase one and doesn' make the iterator go out of bounds when you erase the last element.

Comment: Since this is obviously less flawed, I decided to drop my response in favour of yours :-)

Answer (score 0):

Begemoth's comment should be the accepted answer. <strike>According to the standard erase invalidates "all iterator and references to elements after position"</strike>(*my mistake; this was for vector and possibly other containers; so at least to avoid surprises you should do well to use the algorithm version instead*).

So you'd be safer already using rbegin() and rend(). But why not use the std::alogirthms!

```
struct Predicate 
{
     int _y;
     explicit Predicate(int y) : _y(y) {}

     bool operator()(const CG1_Edge edge) const
     {
          return currentEdge->y_up < _y;
     }
};

std::erase(
     std::remove_if(this->ActiveEdges.begin(), this->ActiveEdges.end(), Predicate(y)),
     this->ActiveEdges.end());
```

Comment: `list::erase` and `vector::erase` are different beasts. `list::erase` only invalidates the iterators positioned at the erased element. not those after, not those before.

Comment: Prefer member-functions when present. They are likely optimized for the container type in question. list::remove_if is better in this situation.

Comment: ... since it actually removes the elements rather than shifting them to the back of container like std::remove_if does. So no erasing is necessary.

Comment: Yup. All true. I like to stick with the algorithms because there will be no surprises when switching from list<> to vector<>. But: awareness trumps convention and optimize when necessary!